# How to make function for HTTP request on other class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http

I'm writing a app to make a http requests with SwiftHTTP, but I want to create a class to make this, and in the ViewController I call the functions to do this. So, I create a UIButton to call the functions.

I don't know if I need use threads or exists ways to make this easy.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(self.clickRequest(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside )        
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func clickRequest (sender: UIButton) {

}

}
```

HTTPService.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftHTTP

class HTTPService {



}
```

How I make this in others Apps. But inside of ViewController.swift.

```
HTTP.GET("https://www.host.com/example",requestSerializer: JSONParameterSerializer()) {
                response in
                if let err = response.error {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }


                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one method with **successBlock** and **failureBlock** inside your `HTTPService` service class like below,

```
class HTTPService {

func makeRequest(params: [String: Any], successBlock: () -> Void, failureBlock: () -> Void) {
    HTTP.GET("https://www.host.com/example",requestSerializer: JSONParameterSerializer()) {
        response in
        if let err = response.error {
           print(err.localizedDescription)
           failureBlock() // Call failure block
           return
        } else {
           successBlock() // Call success block
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
        failureBlock() // Call failure block
    }
}

}
```

You can call this method like below,

```
@objc func clickRequest (sender: UIButton) {
     HTTPService().makeRequest(params:  ["name": "userName"], successBlock: {
        // Handle API success here. E.g Reloading table view
     }) {
        // Handle API failure here. E.g Showing error to user
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This works! But, How do I pass parameters to the function? For example, I need the payload of a HTTP GET (Json object).

Comment: You can simply add one more function parameter in same function. Please see my updated answer.